# Imaginary order polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis

I am currently doing some research on this interesting equation: $ax^i + bx + c = 0$, where $a, b, c$ belongs to the complex numbers.

Is there a way to analytically find the formula for the roots? Also, how do I even determine how many roots this equation can have?

Comment: Wouldn't there be an infinite amount of roots?

Comment: Not really. If you think about it, although taking a number to the ith power yields infinite answer, i.e. +2pi k, where k is an interger, it still needs to satisfy the equation.

Comment: Try to graph this function in domain coloring and you will see why.

Comment: Use this series solution [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418392/series-solution-for-general-trinomial). However, please also expand on your question

Answer (score 7):

First of all, $x^i = \exp(i \log(x))$ is a multi-valued function so you really need to specify which branch of it you are using. Let's say you're using the principal branch of $\log$, so you represent $x = r e^{i\theta}$ with $\log(x) = \ln(r) + i \theta$, $-\pi < \theta < \pi$, and then
$$ x^i = \exp(-\theta + i \ln(r))$$
It looks to me like there can be infinitely many solutions approaching $x = 0$.

As $x \to 0$, i.e. $r \to 0$, $b x + c \to c$, so for a root you'll want
$ \exp(-\theta + i \ln(r)) \approx -c/a$.  For the absolute values to match you'll want $|c/a| \approx \exp(-\theta)$, so $e^{-\pi} < |c/a| < e^\pi $.
And then you should have a solution with $\ln(r) \approx \text{Im}(\log(-c/a)) - 2 \pi n$ for each sufficiently large positive integer $n$.

EDIT: For example, take $a = b = c = 1$, so we're solving $x^i + x + 1 = 0$.  Since $|a/c| = 1$, we'll have $\theta \approx 0$, and $r = e^{-m\pi}$ where $m$ is an odd integer.  Taking $m = 1$, we look for a
solution near $e^{-\pi}$, and find (using Maple) $x = 0.04310018702 - 0.001819854367 i$.

Next, try $m=3$ and $x$ near $e^{-3\pi}$: $x = 0.00008069951678 - 6.512149263 \times 10^{-9} i$.

Next, $m = 5$ and $x = 1.50701727539001 \times10^{-7} - 2.27110092456957 \times 10^{-14} i$.

And so on...

Comment: Since you mentioned that for the root exp(−+ln())≈−/, doesn't also the real and imaginary part stays within 1 + 1i and -1 - i? Also, as x approaches 0, the bx term goes to 0. So I am kinda confused by the explanation but thanks for the explanation. 
. I also graph the function and plugged it into wolframe alpha, there seem to be a finite amount of roots.

Comment: Only the imaginary part of $\log(x)$, i.e. $\theta$. is in the interval $(-\pi, pi)$.  That's why I wanted $|c/a|$ to be between $\exp(\pi)$ and $\exp(-\pi)$.  $\ln(r)$, which is the real part of $\log(x)$, can be anything; in particular if $x$ is near $0$, that's a large negative number.

Comment: So can this be generalize to any “I” order polynomial that they have infinite amount of roots? Even though we cannot order complex numbers.

Comment: Notice I wanted $e^{-\pi} < |c/a| < e^\pi$.  If $|c/a| > e^{\pi}$ or $< e^{-\pi}$, I suspect you'll have finitely many solutions, maybe none (again, using the principal branch of $\log$).